# Working with files, cp1251 and utf-8 encodings

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Rigth now i have something like

```
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

QStringList argList = a.arguments();

if (argList.length() < 2 || argList.length() > 3)
{
    QTextStream(stdout) << "Usage: toGift input_file [output_dir]\n";
    return - 1;
}
```

For decoding Windows-1251 strings, but i still get wrong filename, which is passed through argv. The filename is in cyrillic. Can't firgure out what am i missing

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: And pick one language. **C is not C++ is not C.**

Comment: And how exactly should i post a question, when the code IS working, it is working as it is supposed to, but the question lies in encodings of strings?

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Why do ask then, if "the code IS working"? You have a - well - uncommon definition of "working".

Comment: And you want **us** to dig in the dirt then? Sorry, I'm not [Peter Gabriel](http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/peter-gabriel/digging-in-the-dirt-63d4fa03.html). Clean it up yourself first, you might already solve your problem.

Comment: Sure, but SO is not a debugging or consulting-for-free service.

Comment: Edited the post, still have no clue of what am i missing

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin: how are you using those QStrings to open the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text encodings in Windows console applications is a hairy matter. Tip: use the arguments() member of your QApplication (QCoreApplication if it's a console executable), it retrieves the arguments directly in UTF-16 from Windows, without trying to decode it from the lossy local encoding used for argc/argv.

Comment: well i don't really have that, but thanks for the tip, right now QCoreApp does not exist in my app. I'll have to try it.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin: be careful, many functionalities of Qt don't work (as in: they may even crash your program) if you don't have a QApplication or QCoreApplication instance. Always create one as first thing in any application which uses Qt.

Comment: I only went for QT because i coud not find any other 'easy' way to deal with encodings. Not really used to it. I guess you can't just write a standard console app, with some QT features.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin: well, Qt *is* a framework more than a library, so it has some demands about the structure of the application. However, in simple cases like this all you have to do is `QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);` at the beginning of your `main`.

Answer (score 0):

in the end it came to this:

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
if(codec == 0)
{
    QTextStream(stdout) << "No codec was found" << endl;
}
QTextDecoder *decoder = codec->makeDecoder();

QString inp_fileName = QString(decoder->toUnicode(argv[1]));
................
QFile inp_file(inp_fileName);
if(!inp_file.open(inp_file.ReadOnly))
{
    QTextStream(stdout) << "Could not open file for reading.\n" << inp_file.errorString() << endl;
    return -3;
}
```

I still needed the decoder for further use.